# How to get the first unique number in array using PHP?

Tags: php

Consider an **array [1,2,1,2,3,4,5,]**. I need to make a function in PHP that will return the first unique number in that array, in this case, 3.

Or

How we can remove all repeated elements of the array. In this case returns [3,4,5].

Comment: array_unique??? You mean unique?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the help pages, take the https://stackoverflow.com/tour. Read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example .

Answer (score 1):

You can use following snippet,

```
$yourArr = [1,2,1,2,3,4,5];
// count the number of occurences of each value
$res = array_count_values($yourArr);
// filtering only unique values
$res = array_filter($res, function($item){ return $item == 1; });
print_r();
// to fetched first unique
// fetching filtered values as keys
$un = array_keys($res); 
echo $un[0]; // will output 3
```

[array_count_values](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php) — Counts all the values of an array
[array_filter](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) — Filters elements of an array using a callback function
[array_keys](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) — Return all the keys or a subset of the keys of an array

[Working Demo](https://3v4l.org/rbttE)

**Output:-**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 3
    [1] => 4
    [2] => 5
)
```

Comment: Now can. I ain't updated words but snippet. Now corrected.